# how do set select option 'selected' after load page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code html

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="1" >Date</option>
    <option value="2">Helpfulness</option>
</select>
```

**Updated**

> So when the user selects 'Helpfulness' and reloads page then
> option Helpfulness should be 'selected'. and if 'Date' is choosen
> then reloaded page should set Date 'selected'.

thank for help!

Comment: `$('.mySelect').val(2)`

Answer (score 9):

Use `.val()` to `set` the value to `2` as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.mySelect').val( 2 );
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.mySelect').val( 2 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Date</option>
  <option value="2">Helpfulness</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

Per your updated question use `localStorage` or `cookies` to hold the selected value. When the page refreshes, check for the cookie or localStorage value and load it.

```
$(function() {
    $('.mySelect').on('change', function() {
        $.cookie('mySelect', this.value);
    });
    $('.mySelect').val( $.cookie('mySelect') || 1 );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2jcda405/)

Answer (score 1):

For most default value, it would be easy to set on html markup directly like :

```
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="1" >Date</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Helpfulness</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise, use jQuery `.prop` code here :

```
$( function () {
   $('.mySelect option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value in `val()` and `change()` function

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.mySelect').val(2).change();
});
```